# What is global message pool in Android? Where does it reside in memory?

Tags: android, handler, message

When I was looking up the functionality of **Handler.obtainMessage()**,
 I read that it retrieves a message from global message pool instead of creating a new instance of message.  Where does this global message pool reside?
Is it a collection of all the message objects that were created before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that dalvik stores the messages in a pool of **recycled** objects. These are created and stored from a static pool thread:

```
private static Message sPool;
```

You won't have access directly to it, but you can still call methods such as [recyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#recycle%28%29).

You can have a look at the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/os/Message.java#Message.0sPoolSize).

As for where exactly : the [heap](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#heap).

Answer (score 2):

It's a linked list in `Message`. The head of the list is stored in a `static` variable. [Source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Message.java#106).

Messages are put to the pool with [`recycle()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Message.java#248).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into sources:

```
Message obtain() :
```

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Message.java#106

which is using:

```
private static Message sPool;
```

a static class variable (actually it is a single linked list), so this pool is global to your application.

And in provided link, you can find `public void recycle()` method that returns no longer neede message to above pool.